# Как составить запрос, который выводит список?

Tags: sql

Друзья, помогите разобраться с данным заданием,пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде:

```
SELECT b.name, COUNT(p.*) AS ProductCount, w.name FROM brand b
LEFT OUTER JOIN product p ON p.brandId = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN goods g ON g.productId = p.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN warehouse w ON w.id = g.warehouseId
GROUP BY b.name, w.name
ORDER BY ProductCount DESC
```